# How to call DB function in LINQ with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql

Does EF supports calling functions directly in the LINQ

For example like this?

```
Context.Datas.Where(a => SpecificFunction(a.Created) == 1)
```

Where in T-SQL code it looks

```
select * from Data where dbo.SpecificFunction(Created) == 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the answer:

First we need to import the function to edmx file with designer or manually, then we need to write the function and map it:

```
[EdmFunction("MyNameSpace", "SpecificFunction")]
public static int AvgStudentGrade(DateTime created)
{
throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls are not supported.");
}
```

Manually mapping for edmx can be like this:

```
<Function Name="SpecificFunction" ReturnType="int" Schema="dbo">
<Parameter Name="created" Mode="In" Type="datetime" />
</Function>
```